# $_REQUEST PHP not stable

Tags: php, curl

I upload a file on server using curl as follow:

```
curl -X POST -F "file=@$1" -F 'utk=...' -F 'k=...' http://localhost:8888/LinkToWebservice
```

on server, to debug whether I get the $_REQUEST correct or not, I log it in a file:

```
//- logging
$req_dump = print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE);
$fp = fopen('/var/tmp/myserver.log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $req_dump);
fclose($fp);

//- checking
if (!isset($_REQUEST['k'])) {

            $this->output_result(array(
                'error_message' => 'Invalid API key',
            ), 400);

}
```

The result is so weird. The "curl" command works with file1, but does not work with file2.

the log file I got is:

**file1:**: missing utk, and k parameter

```
array
(
    [querystring] => LinkToWebService
)
```

**file2:** all parameters are available.

```
array
(
    [querystring] => LinkToWebService
    [utk] => ... (available)
    [k] => .... (available)
)
```

***UPDATED***: Another weird thing is file1 cannot be uploaded as mentioned above. But if I rename file1 into "file2", it can be uploaded. and $_REQUEST contains all fields.

Do I have any problem regarding "caching"?

Comment: What is file1 and file2?

Comment: the files I want to upload. I don't want to show the name of my files, so I call them as file1 and file2.